# master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe'

Tags: sql-server

i want to be able to call a **exe** from mssql 
my program is call **scramble.exe** held in c:\test

i have used the following command in sql for testing purposes

*master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe'*

when you execute this it just keeps executing no notepad opens 
but if you open task manager you can see the notepad running 
if you kill this process the query stops

can any one help em with this 
ta
Gerard

Answer (score 6):

It is not working right because you are not supposed to call interactive programs via `xp_cmdshell`. The programs called through `xp_cmdshell` run in background. Try with a  program with no GUI.

Edit: this  goes for all applications that implement dialogues. [This mskb explains it pretty well](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323411).

> If you run a program through the xp_cmdshell extended stored procedure, the program only runs in the background. The xp_cmdshell extended stored procedure does not display the user interface of the programs that run in its context. If an application that is run through xp_cmdshell does needs user interaction from a user interface (for example, the application tries to create a dialog box or a message box that needs user input) it will stop responding because it is waiting for input. However, xp_cmdshell will never display the user interface; therefore, the user cannot provide any input.

Comment: that clarify what is happening thanks. So is there a way using sql to call a .exe

Comment: If your `scramble` program *is not* interactive, you can call it via `xp_cmdshell` and it will work allright. If not, then I have to question why would you want to call and interactive program from SQL ;)