# Open Chrome From Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, database, google-chrome

I have tried to open  Chrome browser from SQL server after inserting the record.

I used following code: but is not seems to work.

```
USE [test]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER trigger [dbo].[testTrig]
on [dbo].[test] after insert
as
declare @sqlstr varchar(1000)
set @sqlstr = 
(select top 1 '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://localhost:60353/test/Index')
exec xp_cmdshell @sqlstr
```

Comment: What do you mean "open"? SQL Server is a background service, it doesn't open applications. You're using completely the wrong tool for whatever it is you're trying to do here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because what is being requested is impossible. SQL Server is a background service, it doesn't "open" applications. A front end application is needed to do automated tasks such as that.

Comment: it is possible to open chrome by execute cmdshell check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql

Comment: How does that page say that is is possible? It really doesn't.

Comment: Do you know,we can open any .exe file using cmd. same thing we are trying to execute in sql server through cmdshell to open chrome

Comment: You can run an executable yes; that isn't the same an opening an application. You **cannot** open an application via `xp_cmdshell`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the query is working fine. It opened the browser in background.

Check here for  @Rodrigo Hahn answer :
 
[master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081945/master-dbo-xp-cmdshell-c-windows-system32-notepad-exe)